# What is the attacking mechanism of RF on IgG?

Tags: molecular-biology, antibody, autoimmune

Rheumatoid Factor (RF) attacks Fc portion of Immunoglobulin G (IgG), I want to know the underlying mechanism at molecular level. Also, what type of bond or attachment is made by RF and Fc portion of IgG?

// I'm a student of mathematical physics and have no detailed knowledge in biology, this question comes in my mind because my sister is suffering from Rheumatoid arthritis. All I want is to understand this disease from physical aspects//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RF factors comprise antibodies that your body makes that exhibit auto-immunity (recognition of self as an antigen). They often recognize and bind to IgG antibodies as illustrated in this picture:
[image: RF binding to IgG]

So the answer to your first question is that the underlying mechanism is inappropriate recognition of self from your immune system.

For your second question, I am not an expert in the type of chemical bonds employed by antibody-antigen interactions, so I looked it up briefly. This article was quite informative for that: [Antibody/Antigen Complexes](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2581910/).  The majority of binding seems to be hydrogen and ionic binding.

Hope that gets you going in your own searches.

Comment: Thanks sir, the link helped me a lot. I was searching something special in bonding of RF & IgG so that we can separate them via external forces. Here uniqueness and speciality is important in the RF-IgG bond because in breaking the bonds from external forces can destroy the bonding between another antigen and antibodies.

Comment: Great.  Mark my answer if it answered your question. That is how it works.

Comment: But I didn't get unique property of RF-IgG bond, the bonding between antigen and antibodies are generalized in that link.

Comment: Antibodies have variable regions that are just that.  Through VDJ recombination, this could be a multitude of ways. I don't know of a way to characterize a unique binding pocket for this process.  You might be able to do so if you could crystallize a monoclonal AB/IgG protein complex.  But my understanding in humans would be you would have many different auto antibodies coming from different B cells.  Anyone else that can chime in, please do.